# Change position of div based on content & viewport height using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position, window-resize

I want to have a div be fixed at the bottom of the window when the window is taller than the content height. If the content height is taller than the window height, I want the div position to remain relative.

I currently have this mostly working, however I don't want the div to overlap the content at all. I tried various forms of below, but still not working:

```
var body = content+bottomBar

if (body > viewport) {
    $(".bottom-bar").css({
      'position':'relative'
    });
} else {
  $(".bottom-bar").css({
    'position': 'fixed'
  })
}
```

I also am having trouble getting the window.resize to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/no05x1vx/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [jsfiddle linked by the OP](http://jsfiddle.net/no05x1vx/1/), here are a few changes to make the code work as expected, please see the comments:

```
var content = $(".content").height()
var viewport = $(window).height();

// Use innerHeight here as the bottom-bar div has height 0 and padding 60px
// .height() would return 0
var bottomBar = $(".bottom-bar").innerHeight();
var body = parseInt(content)+parseInt(bottomBar)

$(window).on('resize', function(){
    // Get new viewport height
    viewport = $(window).height();

    if (content > (viewport-bottomBar) ) {
        $(".bottom-bar").css({
            'position':'relative'
        });
    } else {
        $(".bottom-bar").css({
            'position': 'fixed'
        })
    }
});  

// Trigger resize after page load (to avoid repeated code)
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but something isn't working. I plugged the code into the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/gs5my6ad/) –  should use body > viewport instead?

Comment: Try using a different version of jQuery. It seems to work fine with 1.7.2 or later http://jsfiddle.net/t6h2h4ef/1/